# OnMouseDown doesn't work with custom cursor in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cursor

I am developing an aiming game and would like to replace the mouse cursor with a crosshair. I did that by finding a crosshair sprite, transforming it to texture type: Cursor, and then in the player settings I set the crosshair as default cursor. The crosshair is being displayed successfully during gameplay in the Unity Editor.

I have now different kinds of spheres, which the player has to shoot. Each sphere has this script attached to it:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class DestroyOnTouch : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ParticleSystem sphereExplode;
    private float startTime;

    private void Start()
    {
        startTime = Time.time;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        //Destroy(gameObject, 1.5f);
    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        float RT = Time.time - startTime;
        if (this.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color == Color.red)
        {
            Stats.redCount++;
            Stats.redRTList.Add(RT);
        }
        else
        {
            Stats.greenCount++;
            Stats.greenRTList.Add(RT);
        }
        Deactivate();
    }
    void Deactivate()
    {
        Instantiate(sphereExplode, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

So, when I'm using the mouse cursor to shoot and destroy the spheres, everything works fine. However, when I'm using the crosshair as a cursor, it doesn't destroy the spheres. All spheres have a sphere collider attached to them.

What am I missing here?

Comment: does OnMouseDown gets called?

Comment: Have you debugged it to ensure that the `OnMouseDown` method is being entered? Are there any errors or warnings in the console?

Comment: No errors and no warning in the console. Is there a specific reason why it might work with the mouse cursor and not with the crosshair?

Comment: Are you expecting the hot point of the cursor to be the middle or the corner? What happens if you think of your cross hairs as an arrow and try then? Does it hit now?

Comment: @BugFinder I was expecting the hit point to be the middle of the crosshair but after I read your comment I tried using it as a mouse cursor and it works. The question now is how do I fix this?How do I make make the middle of the crosshair the hit point?

Comment: If you google the set cursor has an option to define the hot point position.